# What is the sum to infinity of an infinite series S?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

> The terms of an infinite series S are formed by adding together the corresponding terms in two infinite geometric series, T and U.
>
> The first term of T and the first term of U are each 4.
>
> In order, the first three terms of the combined series S are 8, 3, and 5/4.
>
> What is the sum to infinity of S?
> $T_1 = 4, U_1 = 4$

$T_2 + U_2 =3$

$T_3 + U_3 = 5/4$

therefore

$4r_t + 4r_u = 3$

$4r_t^2 + 4r_u^2 = 5/4$

How can I continue from there? When I try to solve by replacing $r_u$ with $\frac{3-4r_t}{4}$ I find two values for $r_t$ and I don't know which one is the correct one.

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: "When I try to solve by replacing $r_u$ with $\frac{3−4r_t}{4}$ I find two values for $r_t$ and I don't know which one is the correct one." -- At this point, you should have kept going and tried both values.  You would see that sum of $S$ is the same in both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$r_t + r_u = 3/4$$
$$r_t^2+r_u^2=5/16$$
Squaring the first equation gives
$$r_t^2+2r_tr_u+r_u^2=9/16$$
Then subtracting the second equation from this gives
$$2r_tr_u=1/4\qquad r_tr_u=1/8$$
Thus, the polynomial $r^2-\frac34r+\frac18$ has roots $r_t,r_u$ by Viète's formulas. We get that the roots are $\frac14$ and $\frac12$.
The sum to infinity of $S$ is then the sum to infinity of its components:
$$\frac4{1-1/4}+\frac4{1-1/2}=\frac{16}3+8=\frac{40}3$$

Answer (score 0):

$T_n=4a^{n-1}$ and $U_n=4b^{n-1}$ for some $a$ and $b$.
Then
$$3=4a+4b$$
and
$$\frac54=4a^2+4b^2.$$
Then $a+b=\frac34$ and $a^2+b^2=\frac5{16}$. Then
$$2ab=(a+b)^2-(a^2+b^2)=\frac14$$
so that $a$ and $b$ are the solutions of
$$X^2-\frac34 X+\frac18=0$$
etc.